# 'NoneType' object support error in Hangman

Tags: python

I'm writing a hangman game and found a code online for replacing blank spaces with the letters after a correct guess was made but it unfortunately produces a 'NoneType' error
I'm not sure how to correct it and I haven't been able to apply other answers I've found online to the code to fix it

```
word_list = ['around','august','branch','bright','castle','change','across']
tries = 0
word = random.choice(word_list)
print(word)
blank = print ("_ "*len(word))
while tries < 7:
    guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
    blank = list(blank)
    for k in range(0, len(word)) or []:
        if guess == word[k]:
            blank[k] = guess
    print (''.join(blank))
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace and error to your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the return of print and not the value in print into `blank`

Try this :

```py
import random

word_list = ['around','august','branch','bright','castle','change','across']
tries = 0
word = random.choice(word_list)
print(word)
blank = "_ "*len(word) #storing what you want in variable
print(blank) #print the variable
while tries < 7:
    guess = input("Enter a letter: ")
    blank = list(blank) #here you do list() on the variable and not the return of print >> OK
    for k in range(0, len(word)) or []:
        if guess == word[k]:
            blank[k] = guess
    print (''.join(blank))
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you! :) do you have any idea how to fix the letters not correctly replacing the underscores? for some reason there are always 3 of them remaining

Comment: You should tag this question as Answered and post a new question for new problem for readability of SO